# Foreign key not persisting

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We have two tables `GeneralInfo` and `DetailedInfo`.

`G_Id` is primary key of `GeneralInfo` and foreign key of `DetailedInfo`.

`DetailedInfo` has one  primary key `D_Info`

The relations between two tables are from `GeneralInfo` to `DetailedInfo` as `OneToMany` and from `DetailedInfo` to  `GeneralInfo` as `ManyToOne`.

I get  following error when exceuting:

```
ERROR: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails  
(`Info`.`DetailedInfo`, CONSTRAINT `DetailedInfo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`G_Id`)  
REFERENCES `DetailedInfo` (`G_Id`))

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed;  
nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:  
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:  
could not execute statement
```

Please help us.

In JPA we have given mapping like this:

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "GeneralInfo")

public class GeneralInfoEntity extends AbstractEntity {


    @Id

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    @Column(name = "G_Id")

    private long id;


    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="general") 

    private List<PatientExternalSystemRefEntity> patientExternalSystemRefEntity;

    //follwed by getter and setter

}


@Entity

@Table(name = "DetailedInfo")

public class DetailedInfoEntity extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {


 @Id

 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

 @Column(name = "D_Info")

 private long id;


 @Column(name = "G_Id")         

 private long generalId;


 @ManyToOne

 @JoinColumn(name = "G_Id",nullable=false,insertable=false,updatable=false)

 private GeneralInfoEntity general;

 //follwed by getter and setter

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a new record in `DetailedInfo`? If so, does the G_ID you are inserting(as fk) exists in `GeneralInfo`?

Comment: Can you please show how those `DetailInfo` objects are created/attached to `GeneralInfo`?

Comment: Looks like the primary key is not generated properly. Check the generation strategy of the parent object.